# How to return possible pairs of variables based on a function?

Tags: r

I have a pair of variables (x, y) and for each variable there is a possible range of values (xmin, xmax and ymin, ymax). I am looking for such pairs that based on a function would yield the same probability.

This is my function that would return probabilities.

```
f <- function(x, y) 1-exp(-(x^(1/0.9)+y^(1/0.9))^0.9)
```

Now suppose I want to know that for a certain probability, say 0.01 what are the possible pairs of variables of x and y yielding that (considering their constraints, min and max values).

(What I have already tried is doing the whole thing the other way around by creating a matrix first for x and y and then for each combination I calculated the probability, but then I would need to find the same probabilities in the matrix, which seems to be even more difficult.)

Comment: I think you still need to calculate all the probabilities to find out which has certain value( 0.01). If `matrix2` is the matrix with all the combination of probability, you can do `mat <- which(matrix2 == 0.01, arr.ind = TRUE)` and to get the combinations do `data.frame(comb1 = rownames(matrix2)[mat[, 1]], comb2 = colnames(matrix2)[mat[, 2]])` would this work for you?

Comment: I get your point, which is a good idea and I think it will work, the only thing is that probabilities in my matrix are not round numbers, so R will not find 0.01. I thought about indicating a range there, say 0.01 plus minus 0.0001. How can I add that to the first command? And thanks for helping!

Comment: You can analytically find y yielding to the desired probability if x is given (good old paper and pencil), then loop over x values between min and max by small steps and find the corresponding y. Finally check if y is in the desired range to know if you keep the pair. This is probably really faster since you solve only in one dimension instead of two when computing a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by doing some math (sorry latex formatting is not supported in SO):

`P=1-exp(-(x^(1/0.9)+y^(1/0.9))^0.9)`

`ln(1-P)=-(x^(1/0.9)+y^(1/0.9))^0.9)`

`(-ln(1-P))^(1/0.9)-y^(1/0.9)=x^(1/0.9)`

`((-ln(1-P))^(1/0.9)-y^(1/0.9))^0.9=x`

Now if we put it in some R code, and check when results do not exists :

```
get_x <- function(P,y)
{
  x=((-log(1-P))^(1/0.9)-y^(1/0.9))^0.9
  # Verification of the results
  # If results no real (then x[i]=NaN) or if it does
  # not match the given probability (should never happens)
  # the results is set to NaN
  # This verification is for debugging only, should be removed
  for (i in c(1:length(y))){
    if(is.na(x[i]) | abs(P-1+exp(-(x[i]^(1/0.9)+y[i]^(1/0.9))^0.9))>0.00001)
    {
      x[i]=NaN
      print(paste0("Oops, something went wrong with y=",y[i]))
    }
  }
  return(x)
}

y_values=seq(0.01,0.99,by=0.001)
get_x(0.09,y_values)
```

Which is pretty fast, now only one loop is used, instead of two to fill the matrix, so order n instead of n^2

Comment: Yes, it is clear now. The confusion was that I did not rearrange the formula in the first place, like you did. The code is all clear, I have just run it, it works fine! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate probability for all possible combinations and create a dataframe with combination which satisfies our criteria with some tolerance (for floating point comparison)

```
tol <- 0.0001
mat <- which((matrix2 >= 0.01 - tol) & (matrix2 <= 0.01 + tol), arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(comb1 = rownames(matrix2)[mat[, 1]], comb2 = colnames(matrix2)[mat[, 2]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I need:)

Comment: This works, but if you do some math beforehand you can get more accurate solutions with far less computations

Comment: @Chelmy88
So I am also trying to do what you suggested. I did this, but it does not work for some reason, could you help me out? Thanks
probab <- function(y) {
  y <- 1-exp(-(0.0021^(1/0.75)+speed^(1/0.75))^0.75)
  return(speed)
}
probab(y=0.01)

Comment: and also how to do that in a loop (for a range of probab values) would be another thing...

Comment: @AttilaBorsos See my new answer, there was probably something wrong in your maths